# issue with `cp -dR `

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a directory structure as:`/apps/amr`. I want to take a backup of `amr` as it is(i.e without de-referencing links).Now the /apps directory has a different user and group that it belongs to( and i don't have access to that). I am logged in as a different user and group. So obviously in `/apps` directory executing:

```
    mkdir amr_backup
    cp -dR amr amr_backup
```

doesn't work as permission denied.
So,I am trying to do the same in `/apps/amr` directory as `amr` directory has the same user and group i logged in as. But when executing:

```
    mkdir amr_backup
    cp -dR * amr_backup
```

It shows this error:

```
    cp: cannot copy a directory, `amr_backup`, into itself, `amr_backup/amr_backup'
```

which is obvious because the amr_backup directory itself is within `/apps/amr`.
And also I can see not everything is backed up properly:

```
    du -sh /apps/amr
    8.6G    /apps/amr
    du -sh /apps/amr/amr_backup
    4.3G    /apps/amr/amr_backup
```

So kindly give me a resolution around.

Comment: That actually looks about right... `/apps/amr` is twice the size of `/apps/amr/amr_backup`, which is presumably the size that `/apps/amr` was before you added the second copy in a subdirectory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I say, keep it simple...

```
mkdir .tmp
cp -dR * .tmp/.
mv .tmp amr_backup
```

The glob expansion of `*` will not include anything beginning with `.` so the hidden directory will not itself be a source directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude `amr_backup` from the copy command by using `!(amr_backup)` instead of the `*` wildcard.

```
cp -dR !(amr_backup) amr_backup/
```

The file sizes look ok to me. `amr` is about twice the size of `amr_backup` because it contains `amr_backup`.

Comment: Its somehow not working for me.
        `cp -dR !(amr_backup) amr_backup/` is showing error:`-bash: !: event not found`